# Regex: Break a string based on punctuation

Tags: python, regex

The general purpose is to divide the string in two parts when a hyphen or slash is present. However, breaking the string depends on having before the slash or hyphen any of the key values. Otherwise, the string is kept as original.

For instance, the key values are composed of the following:

```
limitee,corp.,ltee.,co-operative,co-op,ltd.,corp,ltee,coop,ltd,co
```

Then the structure to break the string should be:

```
"ABC KINDER LTD./ KINDER ABC LTEE." --> Did not get correct with current regex
The string is broken in two because ltd. is before slash as a result "ABC KINDER LTD." is kept.

"ABC KINDER LTD/KINDER ABC LTEE." --> Did not get correct with current regex
The string is broken in two because ltd. is before slash as a result "ABC KINDER LTD" is kept.

"ABC BOOKS OF THE WORLD CORP.-LA COMPAGNIE DES LIVRES DU MONDE" --> Got correct this one in regex
The string is broken because of corp. is before hyphen. The final string is "ABC BOOKS OF THE WORLD CORP."

"ABC CO-OP DISTRICT SCHOOLS/ SCOLAIRES DISTRICTS ABC COOP" --> Did not get correct with current regex
The string "ABC CO-OP DISTRICT SCHOOLS" is kept.

"ABC PRE/SCHOOL DISRICTS" is NOT modified because it does not have any of the keywords before the slash.
This case is working as expected with the current regex.
```

The general rule is to have any of the keywords before the slash or hyphen to break. Otherwise, the string is kept in the original form. As a side note, the presence of keyword after the slash or hyphen does not affect the result.

I have tried with the following regex:

```
^(.*(?<!\w)(?:limitee|corp\.|ltee\.|co\-op|ltd\.|corp|ltee|coop|ltd)(?![A-Za-z0-9_\/])[A-Za-z0-9.,&]*?)+(?:[-/](\s*.*))?$
```

However, I am just getting correctly the first section of the string:
`ABC BOOKS OF WORLD CORP./LA COMPAGNIE DES LIVRES DU MONDE`

Basically, because there are no keywords in the second part I am able to get that string correct. However, I am having troubles when having a keyword in the second section of the string (with the previous regex, the second part is taken in the first group and kept the whole string).

How can I get the first section of the string even though there is a keyword in the second section (after hyphen or slash)?

**Update:**
I got rid of the optional for the second group. Now it is mandatory, this change is getting correct results, but not sure it is efficient:

```
^(.*(?<!\w)(?:limitee|corp\.|ltee\.|co\-op|ltd\.|corp|ltee|coop|ltd)(?!\w)?[A-Za-z0-9.,& ]*?)(?:[-/](\s*\w+.*))
```

However, this is not correct because if we have in keywords a substring, then it will not work. For instance, if adding `co` to the keyword list (substring of co-op) then `ABC CO-OP DISTRICT SCHOOLS` and `ABC CO-OPERATIVE DISTRICT SCHOOLS` will be converted to `ABC CO` which is incorrect.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want `^([^-/\n]*\b(?:limitee\b|corp\b\.?|ltee\b\.?|co-?op|ltd\b\.?)[^-/\n]*)(?:[-/]\s*(.*))?$`? See https://regex101.com/r/nmq1mU/1

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, the problem I included in the update is that if in the keyword I have a substring, then is just taking the smallest string in the alternations. For instance, if `co` is added to the keywords, then `ABC CO-OP DISTRICT SCHOOLS` becomes `ABC CO`. How can I say to regex, just search for strings in the order presented in the alternators and do not continue searching. Then, when found `co-op`, the engine would not continue checking for `co`

Comment: You mean you are building the regex dynamically? Use `r'^([^-/]*\b(?:{})(?!\w)[^-/\n]*)(?:[-/]\s*(.*))?$'.format('|'.join(sorted(map(re.escape(terms), key=len, reverse=True))))`

Comment: Yes, I am passing the keywords dynamically, and passing the keywords as parameter to the function. Basically, in the same way you advised: `all_terms.sort(key=len, reverse=True); term_alternators = '|'.join(map(re.escape, all_terms))`. Then term_alternators is used in the regex., they are passed in order, but not sure why `ABC CO-OP DISTRICT SCHOOLS` string with term_alternators such as `CO-OPERATIVE|CO-OP|CO.|CO` as parameter will find first `CO` and brake the first section in there.

Comment: You need to make the first `[^-/]*` lazy, `[^-/]*?`: `r'^([^-/]*?\b({})(?!\w)[^-/\n]*)(?:[-/]\s*(.*))?$'.format('|'.join(sorted(map(re.escape(terms), key=len, reverse=True))))`

Comment: Awesome @WiktorStribiżew!!! It worked, just trying to figure out what is the difference when you apply lazy quantifier in `[^-/]*?` in comparison to `[^-/\n]*`?

Comment: That is easy, the hardest part was to understand you want to get that part of match: nowhere is indicated you are actually *capturing* the keywords.

Comment: i see your edits and concern. substrings are a problem but is easily handled with ws bound `(?<!\S)(?!\S)` but the bigger issue is that all list thangs be forced to consume without giving any back. that is because `-/` delimiters could be contained in item, like `co-op`. if never happens no problem, you get thris https://regex101.com/r/upfilD/1 if problem, than my solution is one you need. if delimiters grow, it spreads into list items, your worst nitmare

Comment: correction last cmt, use assert boundry cause cant just use `\b` on unnkown data `(?:(?=\w)\b|(?!\w))(?: data )(?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<!\w))` See my answer for a dominatehansive solutin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need

```
keywords_rx = '|'.join(sorted(map(re.escape(terms), key=len, reverse=True)))
reg = r'^([^-/]*?\b({})(?!\w)[^-/]*)(?:[-/]\s*(.*))?$'.format(keywords)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VWphRi/1).

The regex will look match like this:

- `^` - start of a string
- `([^-/]*?\b({})(?!\w)[^-/]*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[^-/]*?` - any zero or more chars other than hyphen and slash, as few as possible due to the non-greedy `*?` quantifier
  - `\b(keyword1|kwyword2|...)(?!\w)` - any of the keywords as whole words
  - `[^-/]*` - any zero or more chars other than hyphen and slash, as many as possible due to the greedy `*` quantifier
- `(?:[-/]\s*(.*))?`  - an optional sequence of

  - `[-/]` - a hyphen or slash
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(.*)` - Capturing group 3: any 0 or more characters other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation added :)